# Picasso - Cancelling a priming fetch

Tags: android, picasso

I am porting an existing app over to use Picasso.  The existing app eagerly prefetches all the images in a list view.  I can implement this with Picasso using [fetch](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch%28%29).  However, in the existing app we cancel these prefetches if the user switches activities, this doesn't seem possible in Picasso, cancelRequest only accepts an ImageView or Target.

Is there a way to cancel fetch requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, no.

We are going to be adding request tagging soon which will allow you to cancel batches of requests by tag. This won't be in the forthcoming 2.3 release but probably the following one.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a noop target and then using that for cancelling.  Can you see any problems with this?

Comment: No. We use Object#equals and Object#hashCode for figuring out canceling.